# How to ask an employer for a daily allowance on a business trip

Tags: professionalism, salary, united-kingdom

I am working for a UK-based startup from India (remote job). I am a fresher having experience of approximately six months, so I do not know how to approach a few things. I have been invited by the company for a two-months trip to London to work on some projects. Although this has been mentioned in the invitation letter that the company will take care of all the travel and accommodation for the trip, I personally feel London is an expensive place, and I will not be able to survive there on my Indian salary.

I am planning to talk to the manager in the UK to provide me some kind of daily allowance or some part of the salary in pounds. But to be honest I don't know how to approach or how to manage things on a financial basis while in the UK.

What is the normal procedure of what a company offers when you are invited to some other country as a business trip and how can I ask for the same to my employer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130106/discussion-on-question-by-rahul-how-to-ask-employer-for-daily-allowance-on-busin).

Comment: A keyword in UK expenses policies is "advance". As noun or verb it refers to cash provided to the employee before the trip for expenses covered by the expenses policy (travel & subsistence policy or similar).  That will mainly be food and local transfers if the flights and accommodation are paid for

Comment: *[fresher](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fresher#Noun)* - *"1. (Britain) A first year student at a university. 2. (India) A fresh graduate looking for one's first job."*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply ask what is and where you can find the company policy on business trips.

In this way you will probably be addressed to the document explaining the entire policy and you will get more information than the single question you have now. This will save you from keep asking questions over time, as it is normal to have them coming later.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of different ways companies handle this so talk to your Manager to find out the policy in your company.

The most common are:-

1. A daily allowance (per diem) to cover your stay.
2. Reimbursement of allowed expenses on production of receipts.
3. Provision of Company Credit card for charging expenses to

1 and 2 usually involve you paying out first, if you don't have a credit card and/or don't want to be caught up with currency fluctations they might be able to give you an advance in sterling.

Comment: Sorry, but not "the policy in your area" but "the policy in the UK". There could be an amount that would be generous for India and totally inappropriate for the UK. And I wouldn't have a problem going to India and advancing all the cost on my personal card, but an Indian employee won't be able to do that coming to India. So having them pay out and then reimbursing is totally unacceptable.

Comment: Precisely connect, as Gnash says.  There is a HUGE difference if company "expects them to use their own card".  Furthermore, it doesn't matter where you're from or what your station.  Expensive last-minute airfares can be like 10 thousand bucks. I have never and would never agree to cover such a cost and be reimbursed later.

Comment: I changed area to company, I have seen companies whose expenses policy was totally inadequate for the country employees were sent to!

Comment: @Fattie This is talking about normal daily expenses like meals, not extraordinary, expensive expenses like airfaires. The question already says that the company is covering travel and accomodations.

Comment: @gnasher729 It should really be the policy for travel abroad from your area/branch. In large international corporations at least, my experience is that the local travel policy will typically defines how much I am allowed to spend in different countries but that doesn't mean I am given the same allowance than someone who is employed in that country or meeting me there. And yes sometimes the amounts haven't been updated or make travel difficult but that's still the policy you have to deal with.

Comment: @Barmar - well sure, my point was just that relatively, I myself would never, ever cover such an expense.

Comment: @Fattie That's likely (and I upvoted both your and Alan's answer). What I am saying is that in any case you cannot ask what the policy is for UK-based employees and assume it will be applicable or workable for employees based elsewhere. So asking about "the policy in the UK" is not going to be particularly helpful.

Comment: gotchya now, indeed. (i upvoted the comments, heh)

Answer (score -1):

> I wanted to know what other company offers when you are invited

Yes, on such a trip

1. GENERALLY your accommodation would be fully paid
2. UNFORTUNATELY though, it is somewhat common (let's call it, half the time) that you are expected to **pay for it yourself and then you will be reimbursed**.

(I personally never allow that since I'm a cheap-ass; I won't take part if that's the arrangement. But I'm much older than the OP so I can bully things around!)

Unfortunately **that's the main problem you face, Rahul.** The manager might "casually assume" you can just put a lakh or two INR on your card every week to pay for accommodation.

So you will have to resolve that issue.  First by getting the policy details, and then talking about it if necessary.

If you have to ask it is OK for you to be direct and clear about it, like this:

> "Steve, so excited about the upcoming work in London. One problem, in the email it says the employee would pay for the hotel using the employee's credit card, and then be reimbursed. In my case I have no such card. There's no chance I could get one with a credit limit anything like that high. What to do? Kindly Rahul"

Regarding food, unfortunately

3. I would say, for a programmer going for two months, unfortunately it would probably more commonly be the case that you **DO NOT GET** any money at all for food. Which sucks. (As an actual example, I have had to work on-site for months+ many times, in all parts of the world, for various corporations, and have never gotten "free food" - other than breakfast which often comes as part of the hotel/similar deal.)
4. However sometimes you will indeed get a "daily stipend" which you can spend on anything you want, and realistically in this case it would all go on food.

It's definitely a tricky situation. Especially since it's a startup, they likely have no policy or experience with this. If they are not planning on offering you a daily stipend, all you can really do is "politely ask". What about something like

> "Steve, so excited about the upcoming work in London. One problem I face is that with the high cost of living in London I'll really struggle to pay for meals! Do you think it's possible I could get a small daily stipend in Pounds to go towards costs? Kindly Rahul"

I wouldn't suggest a specific amount, leave it to them. Unfortunately if they DON'T offer a daily stipend (or some other meal plan), there is not much more you can do than that.

Comment: I have never heard of a company refusing to cover food expenses on a business trip (by some method). They might have inadequate amounts or a slow reimbursement process but never an outright refusal, that would be extraordinary.